# Laravel ajax repsonse json with html

Tags: ajax, json, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to do this:

I have a webpage that list hundreds of apartments, I already did it with pagination in laravel, the thing is I have a filter in the same page in left column, and I want to load again the data according to the filter applied by the user using ajax in the conta.

I realized the response is just sending the data filtered but with no design nor html and I need to list again the information with the same design it was displayed before the filter

```
return Response::json( $response );
```

Is there any option to send the response to a view first or a place where I can listed and then return it to the container with style and html.?

I don't know if I was clear please excuse my english.

Thankst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can do something like this:

```
$view = View::make('partial_template')->with('apartments',$apartments)->render();

return array('html' => $view, 'status' => 'OK');
```

It uses a partial template to render the results.

Comment: Thank you, I did what you said but I am getting a  lot of slashes and code in my response like this <li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<section class=\"image imagen_0\, any idea why?

Comment: try 'echo json_encode($response)' instead of return;

Comment: Thank you, solved, I was missing the data.html, I was just passing data.  $("#results").html(data.html);

Answer (score 0):

**For laravel5**

It has been changed in laravel5. If any one looking solution for laravel5 then he should use the following snippet:

```
$view = view('partial_template')->with('apartments',$apartments)->render();
return Response::json(array('html' => $view, 'status' => 'OK'));
```